# How to use host network for docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker compose with the host network.

I have a docker container that access a local REST api.  Usually I run

```
docker run --net=host -p 18080:8080 -t -i containera
```

which can access the host REST api which runs at `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. Since I want to scale the container `containera` I found docker compose to scale the container. But the docker compose file from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) does not work. The docker container does not query the REST API.

I tried the following compose file but the property

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: conatinera:latest
    network_mode: "host"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 4G 
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
```

but the property `network_mode` is ignored/not allowed.  with the message

```
Ignoring unsupported options: network_mode
```

Comment: Are you using docker swarm? How are you deploying? `docker-compose up` or `docker stack deploy`? Depending on this your current compose file can have several mistakes on it.

Comment: Currently I use the swarm. but when I use docker-compose up also returns `services.web.build contains unsupported option: 'network'`

Comment: Swarm and compose deployments are very different and your yml file is mostly invalid in both modes because you are mixing options from both modes. Please indicate what deployment method are you intending to use so you can get a proper answer (and add the docker-swarm tag and remove the docker-compose one depending what answer do you want)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I want to use compose deployment and will add it to the question

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The equivalent configuration for docker-compose v3 is using the `network_mode` key: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode

You should set `network_mode` to `"host"` in your `docker-compose.yml`.

If using docker swarm, see [codestation's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56586535/576932).

Comment: How can I use this network mode for version 3 in a swarm? or how can I add the network mode since I get a unsupported compose file version different from 3

Comment: `network_mode` is used in v3 and v2. v1 called it `net`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#net

Comment: I added `net` to  my compose file but the net property is ignored

Comment: With the compose file in your updated question, you have `version: "3"`, so you should be using `network_mode`.

Comment: tried both but the `network_mode` still get the ignore

Comment: When you set `network_mode` `host` you should get rid of the `networks`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777655/docker-error-only-one-instance-of-host-network-is-allowed

Comment: as @Ntwobike also mentioned, you can enable host in build property as well

Answer (score 74):

You are mixing options that are invalid on either compose and swarm deployments.

If you are deploying with docker-compose up then your compose file should be like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: conatinera:latest
    network_mode: "host"        
    restart: on-failure
```

Te options `deploy` is ignored on compose mode and the ports option is ignored when using host mode networking. I recommend to don't use host mode networking and use a reverse proxy in another container to balance your scaled containers.

---

(Feel free to ignore this part of the answer as you clarified that you aren't using swarm deployments).

If you are using swarm deployment then your compose file should be like this:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  web:
    image: conatinera:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 4G 
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - host

networks:
  host:
    name: host
    external: true
```

Again, published ports and host mode networking do not mix. Also is probably that your scaling will fail because all the containers will try to bind to the same port. I recommend to don't use host mode networking and let docker load balance your replicas.

Comment: I get this error: `networks.host Additional property name is not allowed`

Comment: I get this error: `Error response from daemon: network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks`

Answer (score 27):

I was facing the same problem. I found that when `network_mode` is set to `host`, port mapping doesn't work as the container will look for the port of the host. So, removing the port mapping worked for me like the following.

```
services:
  web-abc:
    build: ./abc
    # ports:
    #   - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    network_mode: host
```

Answer (score 16):

In docker compose this worked perfectly

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

here is an explanation [What is the equivalent of --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway in a Compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725881/what-is-the-equivalent-of-add-host-host-docker-internalhost-gateway-in-a-comp)

Comment: If host REST api considers a client's request URL it will be like **http(s)://host.docker.internal/restservice** in your case, so if it is needed to get some specific URL feel free to use any alias instead of **host.docker.internal**, for example: `specific-url.local:host-gateway`

Comment: Inside the container on a MacOS you may need to use  docker.for.mac.host.internal instead of host.docker.internal

Answer (score 9):

Which platform you are on? `host` mode is working in Linux only AFAIK. If `network_mode` is not working try `network: host`?

```
version: '3.4'
serivces:
  some_service:
  build:
    network: host
```

Comment: On arch linux I get the error message ` services.web.build Additional property network is not allowed`

Comment: on Ubuntu: Unsupported config option for services.build: 'network'

Comment: This was the issue with my configuration, thank you

Answer (score 7):

i think you should define the docker-compose file like this:
This is just an example, please read the docuementation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: conatinera:latest
    networks:
      mynetwork: {}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 4G 
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "18080:8080"
networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true
    name: host
```

Comment: I get the error message `name Additional property name is not allowed`

Comment: try to use the version 3.7 of docker-compose

Comment: I get this error: `Error response from daemon: network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks`

Answer (score 2):

network_mode: host is not allowed in swarm mode.

Answer (score 2):

I myself did not have success with `networks` or `network_mode`, but if you want to access a network service on the host, you can simply have the host service listen on the `docker0` network interface, which is accessible from the container (depending on your network mode) at the same ip address.  Proof of concept below.

On the host:

```
$ ip -4 a | grep docker0
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0

$ echo hello world | nc -l -p 8888 -s 172.17.0.1
```

On the container:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine nc -w1 172.17.0.1 8888
hello world
```

Another way to make a host service accessible to a docker container is to listen on a unix socket, which can be mounted in the container.