# Docker ERROR: only one instance of "host" network is allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7, docker-swarm

I am trying to run a container where I need to user network driver as "host" instead of "bridge". I am running it on Centos machine and my docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testContainer:
    build:
      context: .
      args: 
        HADOOP_VERSION: 2.6.0
        HIVE_VERSION: 1.1.0
    image: testcontainer
    container_name: testcontainer
    hostname: testcontainer
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
      - 5601:5601
      - 9001:9001
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1  
    networks:
      - elknet  

networks:
  elknet:
    driver: host
```

But i am getting the following error when I fire "***docker-compose up***" :

> ERROR: only one instance of "host" network is allowed

Can anyone please suggest how can I use host network using docker-compose.yml.

Also note that if I use network_host as suggested by @larsks, I am still getting error

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  testContainer:
    build:
      context: .
      args: 
        HADOOP_VERSION: 2.6.0
        HIVE_VERSION: 1.1.0
    image: testcontainer
    container_name: testcontainer
    hostname: testcontainer
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
      - 5601:5601
      - 9001:9001
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1  
    network_mode: host
```

I am getting following error

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> Unsupported config option for services: 'testContainer'

Answer (score 15):

Get rid of the `networks` section in your `docker-compose.yml`, and add a [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) directive to your service definition:

```
services:
  testContainer:
    build:
      context: .
      args: 
        HADOOP_VERSION: 2.6.0
        HIVE_VERSION: 1.1.0
    image: testcontainer
    container_name: testcontainer
    hostname: testcontainer
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
      - 5601:5601
      - 9001:9001
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1  
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: @Iarsks It throws this error when I use "network_mode: host" ---> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'testContainer'

Comment: It looks like you're working with Docker Swarm, which has different behavior. Your question has been linked to a duplicate that has the answer you need.

Comment: Hello, in my case I have to remove the section `networks` inside my service, in your example should be `testContainer`. Apparently the keywords `networks`  and `network_mode` are mutual exclusive and won't live together on the same service.