# Docker serve NestJs on local network

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm coding with `NestJS` and using `Docker`, I can't configure my own `docker-compose` file to serve on the local network card with IP `192.168.1.7`.

i saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56582446/1830228) before.

`Docker` subnet: `192.168.65.0`

```yaml
networks:
  host:
    name: mamanpaz
    external: true
  lan_access:
    driver: bridge

services:
  application:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apps/application/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:dev application
    env_file:
      - apps/application/.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - register
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - default
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

`docker network ls` command output

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                  DRIVER    SCOPE
2b6d6312d176   bridge                bridge    local
a776b0af5ba3   host                  host      local
b152fd5400db   mamanpaz_default      bridge    local
4b401d652fb2   my-network            bridge    local
6476cf7a691a   none                  null      local
```

Comment: You can use the host network in Docker: https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/

Comment: @jabaa i didn't get your meant

Comment: You can configure your servers to listen on your local IP address using the host network. You write: _"I can't configure my own d`ocker-compose` file to serve on the local network card with IP `192.168.1.7`."_, but technically it's possible.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use the "start:dev" command instead of compiling the application and using "npm start" to run the production build? Usually this is the better approach when creating docker containers.

Comment: @jabaa my problem is i don't know how can i configure that, could you update my `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus my application is under development and it in's done yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use host network for docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582446/how-to-use-host-network-for-docker-compose)

Comment: You do **not** need or want host networking for this.  The existing `ports:` setting should be enough; assuming you're not using a VM-based solution like Docker Desktop, that should make the container visible on port 3000 on all host interfaces, and from their your local network.

Comment: The Angular dev server is bound to the localhost IP. If you start it inside a container, you also have to modify this configuration, otherwise you can't reach the server. I don't know NestJs, but it's probably the same dev server. Either use a production-ready server (also for dev) or check the configuration.

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm using Docker Desktop and how can i change port? i tested `posrt: '80:3000` but when i try to open local network ip which that's `http://192.168.1.7` i get refused error

Comment: @jabaa i saw the your referred link, i have the same problem, and i checked `extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` and `network_mode: host` but i can't. could you updare my `docker-compose.yaml` please?

Comment: No, I wouldn't write a duplicate answer. If this is the solution, your question should be closed as duplicate. You can't use `networks` with `network_mode: host`.

Comment: @jabaa But host networking mode is not necessary. If the dev server starts bound to `127.0.0.1:3000` within the container, then the server would also not be accessible from remote LAN machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling `Debian` distribute via `Settings->Resources -> WSL integration` in `Docker Desktop` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're accessing the API on port 3000, not with the IP alone. Otherwise, you need to forward port 80:3000 (assuming NestJS is actually configured to run on port 3000)

Comment: port of `3000` is free and when i change left part of port to 80 i get refused connection of `192.168.1.7`, could you please update my `docer-compose. yaml`?

Comment: I can't update your file if I don't know if your server is actually started on port 3000, or something else. You need to use `sudo docker compose up` to bind to port less than 1024. But as mentioned, you should access http://192.168.1.7:3000 anyway, not modify the forwarded port (and you've not clarified what the server port is actually using)

Comment: My application is launched on port 3000 because it is easily accessible with the addresses `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/`. However, I cannot access it with the local IP address `http://192.168.1.7:3000`. i updated `docker-compose.yaml` on my question

Comment: Okay, well, the Docker Compose doesn't control external IP access, so sounds like your OS firewall is blocking external connections from other machines