# Django cannot send email with gmail smtp using Docker, working without docker

Tags: django, docker, smtp, gmail

I developed a Django app that sends verification code via email.
When **I run the code locally using like PyCharm my code works and emails are being sent.**

Then I wanted to contenerize my application using Docker. I did, but everything works beside the sending email. I get the following error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002) when executing email.send().
I use private network at home. Port 587 is not blocked.

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc \
    && pip install psycopg2

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy main.sh
COPY ./main.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/main.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/main.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# run main.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/main.sh"]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 587:587
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=db_name
      - DB_USER=db_user
      - DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
      - EMAIL_FROM=email@gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_USER=email@gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=password
      - EMAIL_PORT=587
    depends_on:
      - db


  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=db_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_pass

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `network-mode` to `host` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56582574/3760216)

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/usr/src/app/
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=db_name
      - DB_USER=db_user
      - DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
      - EMAIL_FROM=email@gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_USER=email@gmail.com
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=pass
      - EMAIL_PORT=587
    depends_on:
      - db


  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=db_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=db_pass

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: (root) Additional property network_mode is not allowed when added as you shown. When I add it below volumes of backend service I get the following django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Comment: @MateuszSzczepek Please update my answer and place the proper format for `docker-compose` file.

Comment: Amended your answer, the network_mode is added below volumes. This set up gives error when doing docker-compose up: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known