# Nodejs redis not connecting with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I am simply connecting redis server from docker compose networks but its showing timeout error. I tried with localhost etc but its not working with that also. Here is my app.js

```js
import express from "express"; 
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const apiPrefix = process.env.API_PRIFEX;

const client = await createClient(
{
    url: 'redis://redis:6379'
})
on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
.connect();

client.set('visits', 0);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
res.send("Number of visits is " + visits)
client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
})
res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Server1 running." });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(service is up and running on Port:${port});
});
```

But the issue is that it shows: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this I try with port and without port as well but nothing is working.

```yaml
version: "3" 
    services:   
       redis:     
           image: "redis"     
           ports: 
               - "6379:6379"   
       node-app:     
           build: .     
               ports: 
                   - "4001:3000"`
```

I have tried with different host name local host etc but in answers I have find I need to connect only with image name but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

- Create this files for **redis** in **docker**.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis-container
    image: redis:6.2.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./redis-backup:/data
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

  node-app:
    container_name: node-app
    build:
      context: ./node-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "npm i && nodemon index.js"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./node-app:/home/node-app
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

- Create Dockerfile in `node-app` folder
  **./node-app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18.16.0-bullseye as builder

WORKDIR /home/node-app

COPY . .

RUN npm install \
    npm install -g @vercel/ncc

RUN ncc build build/index.js -o dist

FROM node:18.16.0-bullseye as release

WORKDIR /home/node-app
COPY --from=builder /home/node-app/dist .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

- Create redis-backup file folder.
- Create **redis.conf** file.

**redis.conf**

```bash
protected-mode no
port 6379
requirepass mypassword
maxmemory 1gb
```

You can edit your files for this codes and files.

Answer (score -1):

---

The issue that you are encountering is that the address 127.0.0.1 in a docker container refers to itself, not to the host OS.

There are three ways you can solve that, both involve adding the `network` attribute:

- You can run your nodejs container with the property `network_mode: host`. For more information refer to that answer from: [Codestation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582446/how-to-use-host-network-for-docker-compose/56586535#56586535)
- You can also create a link between your containers and you will be able to access your redis container from your container with the hostname `redis` or `redisdb`

```yaml
version: "3" 
    services:   
       redis:     
           image: "redis"     
           ports: 
               - "6379:6379"   
       node-app:     
           build: .     
           ports: 
               - "4001:3000"
           links:
               - "redis:redisdb"
```

- The last way would be to create your own network that can easily connect multiple containers with each other, and they will be able to access each other with their names as hostnames:

```yaml
version: "3" 
    services:   
       redis:     
           image: "redis"     
           ports: 
               - "6379:6379"
           networks:
               - mynetwork
       node-app:     
           build: .     
           ports: 
               - "4001:3000"
           networks:
               - mynetwork
    networks:
       mynetwork:
           name: mynetwork,
           driver: bridge
```

I hope that this was helpful for details check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: None of the things described in this answer are necessary.  As described in the link at the end of the answer, Compose automatically creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it.  `links:` are an obsolete artifact of the original Docker networking setup; host networking generally disables Docker networking functionality and isn't required here.